# How to use tensorflow to approximate hessian matrix's norm

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wonder is there any method to recompute gradients with updated weights within a graph or if there is any better way to do this. For example, for estimating hessian norm, we need to compute

```
delta ~ N(0, I)
hessian_norm = 1/M \sum_{1}^{M} gradient(f(x+delta))- gradient(f(x-delta))/(2*delta)
```

we need to gradient value on `x+delta`. Currently we will get `None` type if we use `tf.gradient` on `var+delta` directly.

More specifally speaking, if we define

```
a = tf.Variable
b = some_function(a)
grad = tf.gradients(b, a)
```

that's a normal gradient computation but if we do

```
grad_delta = tf.gradients(b, a+delta)
```

it will return `None`. This feature seems to make it impossible to approximate the hessian norm using the above method.

Answer (score 1):

`b` is not a function of `a+delta`, so you get `None`s. You either need to create new value `b2` which depends on `a+delta`, or just move your `a` variable by `delta` and eval again to get second value.

This is similar to how you do [line search in TensorFlow](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/dca1d5a65dc4e48f46cc137592d4bae7a16c0031/line_search_example/line_search_example.py).

Comment: Thank you very much. But it still occurs if I did a2 = a + delta,  grad = tf.gradients(b, a2).

Comment: is there a path between b and a2 in your computation graph?